# jQuery-Plugin jqPrint - toggle visibility of print-control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, css, printing

i'm using the jQuery Plugin [jqPrint](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint) to print only a container control on the page(in my case a Table). This "print-container" should be invisible by default (`display:none`).

So i tried to toggle the visibility with the jQuery Functions `show/hide` or `toggle`.
But the control will only be printed when it is visible by default.

This is the print-button, i tried following without success:

1.

```
<input type="button" style="width:120px" onclick="javascript:$('#TblPrinterView').toggle().jqprint().toggle(); return false;" value="Print" title="Print" />
```

2.

```
<input type="button" style="width:120px" onclick="javascript:var tblprint=$('#TblPrinterView');tblprint.show();tblprint.jqprint();tblprint.hide(); return false;" value="Print" title="Print" />
```

As i already mentioned, the table will only be printed when its initially visible. Otherwise `show()` or `toggle()` will make it visible, the printer dialog is shown, but it won't be printed.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**:
The solution was - thanks to waxolunist - to define a media print css. On this way i event don't need to toggle visibility of the printable-control. It can be invisible(display:none) by default.

This is the jQuery function to print the control:

```
<input type="button" style="width:120px" onclick="javascript:$('#TblPrinterView').jqprint(); return false;" value="Print" title="Print" />
```

and this is the stylesheet:

```
@media print 
{
    .TblPrinterView{display:block;}
}
```

Here is the [Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint):

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Eros Fratini - eros@recoding.it
// jqprint 0.3
//
// - 19/06/2009 - some new implementations, added Opera support
// - 11/05/2009 - first sketch
//
// Printing plug-in for jQuery, evolution of jPrintArea: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jPrintArea
// requires jQuery 1.3.x
//
// Licensed under the MIT license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

(function($) {
    var opt;

    $.fn.jqprint = function (options) {
        opt = $.extend({}, $.fn.jqprint.defaults, options);

        var $element = (this instanceof jQuery) ? this : $(this);

        if (opt.operaSupport && $.browser.opera) 
        { 
            var tab = window.open("","jqPrint-preview");
            tab.document.open();

            var doc = tab.document;
        }
        else 
        {
            var $iframe = $("<iframe  />");

            if (!opt.debug) { $iframe.css({ position: "absolute", width: "0px", height: "0px", left: "-600px", top: "-600px" }); }

            $iframe.appendTo("body");
            var doc = $iframe[0].contentWindow.document;
        }

        if (opt.importCSS)
        {
            if ($("link[media=print]").length > 0) 
            {
                $("link[media=print]").each( function() {
                    doc.write("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "' media='print' />");
                });
            }
            else 
            {
                $("link").each( function() {
                    doc.write("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "' />");
                });
            }
        }

        if (opt.printContainer) { doc.write($element.outer()); }
        else { $element.each( function() { doc.write($(this).html()); }); }

        doc.close();

        (opt.operaSupport && $.browser.opera ? tab : $iframe[0].contentWindow).focus();
        setTimeout( function() { (opt.operaSupport && $.browser.opera ? tab : $iframe[0].contentWindow).print(); if (tab) { tab.close(); } }, 1000);
    }

    $.fn.jqprint.defaults = {
        debug: false,
        importCSS: true, 
        printContainer: true,
        operaSupport: true
    };

    // Thanks to 9__, found at http://users.livejournal.com/9__/380664.html
    jQuery.fn.outer = function() {
      return $($('<div></div>').html(this.clone())).html();
    } 
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already try to make your container only visible in printMode with CSS?
I mean with css media=print visible and with media=screen invisible?

```
  @media print {
    body { font-size: 10pt }
  }
  @media screen {
    body { font-size: 13px }
  }
  @media screen, print {
    body { line-height: 1.2 }
  }
```

This means, the first statement is only executed on print, the last on print and screen. A list of media types is available http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html.

That way you can control your css dependent on which device it is shown.

Comment: No, can you please explain that in more detail?  Thank you.

Comment: In your css you can make sections specific to output devices:  @media print {
    body { font-size: 10pt }
  }
  @media screen {
    body { font-size: 13px }
  }
  @media screen, print {
    body { line-height: 1.2 }
  }